# Python BS4: ignore parent directory

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm trying to create a very simple scraper, but I have this problem that I want to do a `continue` inside a for loop if the given criteria is met. Basically I want the for loop to just continue by NOT creating a folder when the `link.text` is equal to `Parent Directory`. The exclusion part is on line 48. It created "Parent Directory" always.

I'm using this: http://artscene.textfiles.com/music/mods/MODS/MODLAND/Maktone/ as a test, and if you enter the website there's "Parent Directory" at the top which I'm trying to ignore in my script.

What am I doing wrong?

```
# Import what's needed
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import requests
from pathlib import Path

# Our base URL where files and sub-directories are located
# Script will download every file with the given extension(s)
# and if you want it to go through sub-directories it also will
# do that
urlInput = input('Enter a URL to scape: ')

# Download directory
dirInput = input('Enter directory name: ')

# Our download directory where all the files will be stored
# This is basically the script location and the download directory within
downloadDir = os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'download' + '\\' + dirInput + '\\'

# Extensions and exclude list
# Extensions are files we want to download
# Exclude's are link text's we want to ignore
exts = ['.mod', '.xm', '.it']
excludes = ['parent directory']

# Download given URL
# to given destination directory
def run(url, dest):

    # Grab page
    request = requests.get(url)

    # Create destination directory
    Path(dest).mkdir(parents = True, exist_ok = True)

    # Parse the HTML data
    html = request.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    # Go through every link
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):

        # Grab href and link text (for naming purpose)
        href = link.get('href')
        text = link.text

        # Do some excludes
        if text.lower in excludes:
            continue

        # Grab the file extension from the URL
        hrefExt = os.path.splitext(href)[1]

        # Check that the file in this iteration is
        # in the extensions list
        if hrefExt in exts:
            file = requests.get(url + href)
            open(dest + text, 'wb').write(file.content)
            print('Downloaded: ' + url+text)

        elif (href.endswith('/')):
            run(url + href, dest + text + '\\')

run(urlInput, downloadDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay never mind.. I forgot the parenthesis on `lower`... Solved.